# How to do multiclass classification for unlabeled data in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, regression, logistic-regression

I have a data with 20 different types (as a column), 10 out of 20 are useful information, I wanted to classify them into 10 different class using logistic regression, as a result I wanted to show the number of records in each class. Data is not labeled.

```
183820,9.17101300730551E+018,9,7,79,169,2017,10,17,6,3,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,637126.9861,5399201
183821,9.17101300712351E+018,9,7,72,147,2017,10,8,6,3,6,2,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,639046.3051,5363761.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try the below reference:

1) A Robust Ensemble Approach to Learn From Positive and Unlabeled Data Using SVM Base Models http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.3144 (published in Neurocomputing)

2) Assessing binary classifiers using only positive and unlabeled data: http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.06837

Answer (score 1):

Split each line and make a table like this

```
table = []
with open('your.csv') as f:
    for l in line:
        table.append(l.split(','))
```

And then use whatever logistic regression function that you prefer and get the result.

Comment: I confused about the logistic regression algorithm, can you please share some link?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the data from a CSV file and then try the clustering method for classification.